# nouveau driver Horizontal Lines Tearing on nvidia Quadro K600 Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, display-resolution, nouveau

I'm facing a problem with my graphics. First I installed the Nvidia driver but I wasn't able to find the resolution 1280x1024, I tried:

```
xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  108.88  1280 1360 1496 1712  1024 1025 1028 1060  -HSync +Vsync                                                                                              
xrandr --addmode DVI-I-0 1280x1024_60.00
```

with no success.

So I turned to the "nouveau" driver, and it works I get the resolution 1280x1024, but the quality is poor when I click on a window and I drag it, I get Horizontal Lines Tearing also when I play videos on youtube or Netflix the video get Horizontal Lines Tearing, anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "distorted" do you mean a moire effect, or every n rows/columns a little wider?  It sounds to me like your display may not support that resolution and the driver is performing some interpolation.  More information needed.

Comment: ghedger42 thanks for your concern i ve been looking for the exact therm to my issue,so  this distortion  is called " Horizontal Lines Tearing" sorry my english is not very good and about the resolution of my monitor im pretty sure that it s the right one 100/100